# Error when using a newly installed module with Perl 5.26

Tags: perl, module

I have just installed Strawberry Perl 5.26 on a Win32 machine (XP), and installed Device::ParallelPort (with cpanm, and the installation is OK).

When I try to use the module, I have :

```
    Device::ParallelPort unabel to create driver auto (see Device::ParallelPort::drv::auto for further information) - Device::ParallelPort::
drv::auto (auto detect) error
failed to load win32 - Can't locate Device/ParallelPort/drv/win32.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Device::ParallelPort::drv::win
32 module) (@INC contains: Q:/APPS/Perl-5.26/perl/site/lib/MSWin32-x86-multi-thread-64int Q:/APPS/Perl-5.26/perl/site/lib Q:/APPS/Perl-5
.26/perl/vendor/lib Q:/APPS/Perl-5.26/perl/lib) at (eval 3) line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 3) line 2.
. Make sure you have loaded and installed Device::ParallelPort::drv::win32 from CPAN. Install Device::ParallelPort::drv::(linux|parport|
win32) and try again at (eval 2) line 3.
 at Q:\VirtualDiskII\Perl\testlpt.pl line 25.
```

So I have installed Device::ParallelPort::drv::win32 (and the installation is OK). When trying to use the module, I have :

```
    Device::ParallelPort unabel to create driver auto (see Device::ParallelPort::drv::auto for further information) - Device::ParallelPort::
drv::auto (auto detect) error
failed to load win32 - Failed to load inpout32.dll - Can't create Inp32 2 - Une requÛte d'envoi ou de rÚception de donnÚes n'a pas ÚtÚ a
utorisÚe car le socket n'est pas connectÚ et (lors de l'envoi sur un socket datagramme en utilisant un appel sendto) aucune adresse n'a
ÚtÚ fournie. at Q:/APPS/Perl-5.26/perl/site/lib/Device/ParallelPort/drv/win32.pm line 75.
. Make sure you have loaded and installed Device::ParallelPort::drv::win32 from CPAN. Install Device::ParallelPort::drv::(linux|parport|
win32) and try again at (eval 2) line 3.
 at Q:\VirtualDiskII\Perl\testlpt.pl line 25.
```

Any ideas ?

Thank you by advance !

Comment: This might be due to the version of Perl you're using. What does `perl -V` say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Device::ParallelPort::drv::win32](https://metacpan.org/pod/Device::ParallelPort::drv::win32) docs...

> Standard installation, but you also need "inpout32.dll" which may require either putting into your windows System directory, or at the location of your executable.
>
> inpout32.dll actually comes from a 3rd party source and is freely available.
>
> http://www.logix4u.net/inpout32.htm

Unfortunately that site appears to no longer work. You'll have to find another source.

If you wanted to get ambitious, you could patch the module to handle this automatically and, if the DLL's license allows, ship with the DLL. Or write an [Alien](https://metacpan.org/pod/Alien) wrapper module.

Comment: It seems to work ! The inpout32.dll can be found at http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/inpout32/ and I just put it in the system32 folder. Thank you !